# How convert Object to Function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I convert the Object into a function

```
var FRUIT = {};
FRUIT.color={
    name: "",
    foo: function(){
        return this.name;
    },
    yellow: {
        yellow1: 0,
        yellow2: 0
    }
};

var castFunction = function(){};
$.each( FRUIT.color, function(i, prop){
    castFunction.prototype[i] = prop;
});

var classSmall = new castFunction();
var classBig = new castFunction();

classSmall.name="Yellow small Fruit";
classBig.name="Yellow big Fruit";

classSmall.yellow.yellow1=100;
classBig.yellow.yellow1=10000;

console.log( classSmall.foo() );//Yellow small Fruit ==> OK
console.log( classBig.foo() );//Yellow big Fruit ==> OK
console.log( classSmall.yellow.yellow1 );//10000 ==> why
```

I set it 100 instead of 10000 
why first class value can be changed from the second class.

Actually, the above problem is not a problem if I use the function but I just wanted to know where the errors above or indeed it could not be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
var A = function(foo) {                                                                                                      
    var B = function() {                                                                                                       
        return A.prototype.constructor.apply(B, arguments);
      };
      B.prototype = A.prototype;                                                                                                 
      return B;                                                                                                                  
    };
```